# Broken indentation for Qt-specific constructions in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, editor, indentation

Automatic indentation in VS editor obviously does not know about Qt. And declarations of signals and slots are auto-formatted like this:

```
   class MyClass : public QObject
   {
   Q_OBJECT
   public:
      MyClass();

signals: // <-- Broken indentation
      void someSignal();

      public slots: // <-- Also broken
         void someSlot();
   };
```

I want "signals:" and "slots:" automatically formatted just like access specifiers. What are the options? (I'm using VS2010)

Comment: You might want to consider QtCreator.

Comment: No, changing an IDE is not an option: we use VS for many years now and we're happy with it :)

Comment: Yes, we use the Qt Add-in from Nokia. It doesn't seem to have any features regarding code formatting

Comment: Yes!! I noticed this problem too in vs 2008. Nothing to do about it.

Comment: Still no answer... I'll probably try to write a plugin :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short answer seems to be NO. Maybe not what you are looking for but maybe you can live with this:

```
class MyClass : public QObject
   {
   Q_OBJECT
   public:
      MyClass();

   private:
      Q_SIGNAL void someSignal();

   public:
      Q_SLOT void someSlot();
   };
```

(It's ugly but it seems you can't have your cake and eat it too ;)

Just something I'm wondering about: Is it worth the effort to build a plugin for automatic formatting? Do we really use CTRL-A CTRL-F so much? If so, then yes it could be a pain. But normally if you are working on header files declaring a new method (signal or slot) should not mess up the previous corrected indentation. Perhaps you have some reasons that justifies this?

Comment: Thanks for the hint with macros. It's sort of a habit, to run auto-format each time I edit the file. Also I consider it a "broken window" in my shiny devel environment :-) Writing a separate plugin is an overkill, but a small patch to the Qt add-in for VS could be nice. MB I'll give it an effort.