# Visual Studio's 'Format document' doesn't recognize Q_FOREACH macro

Tags: visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2017, code-formatting

I've noticed that Qt's [`Q_FOREACH`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#Q_FOREACH) macro doesn't play well with certain features of Visual Studio:

1. IntelliSense detects it as a function declaration: every `Q_FOREACH` is displayed as a function/method in the class viewer. Fortunately [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21622264/1485885) solves that problem.
2. Code formatting also detects it as a function declaration (*Edit > Advanced > Format Document*). For example, for my current format style:

   ```
   void foo() {
   Q_FOREACH (auto action, actions){ (action);
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { (i);
   }
   }
   ```

   is formatted as

   ```
   void foo()
   {
     Q_FOREACH(auto action, actions)
     {
       (action);
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
       (i);
     }
   }
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   void foo()
   {
     Q_FOREACH (auto action, actions) {
       (action);
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
       (i);
     }
   }
   ```

Is there any way to fix it? The *cpp.hint* hint used to solve the first problem related to IntelliSense is already applied and hasn't helped with the format.

PS: I'm working with Visual Studio Professional 2017 and using Visual Studio Add-in 2.1.1 for 2017 (beta 10.03.2017, downloaded from https://download.qt.io/development_releases/vsaddin/).

---

**Update:** To give some additional context, we've just started the migration from VS 2010 to VS 2017. Currently we've only migrated the IDE, toolsets are still on 2010, where the natural replacement, the C++11 range-for, is not available for that version of the C++ compiler.

Up to know, some of the members of the team have been using [AStyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) (and [its VS plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Lukamicoder.AStyleExtension2017)) for code formatting, which deals with this situation (and other Qt related things) in a more or less acceptable fashion. I began to study the possibility of migrating to the native code formatter and found this, that's why I posted this question.

---

Related questions that haven't solved my problem:

- [Broken indentation for Qt-specific constructions in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496811/broken-indentation-for-qt-specific-constructions-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The fix is very simple: don't use that macro. It's unnecessary. Use range-for instead. You want to write:

```
void foo()
{
  for (auto action : actions)
    action->doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know, and I'd like to, but, sorry, I forgot to mention that we are just on a migration from 2010 to 2017, and currently the toolsets are anchored on 2010 (where the C++11 range-for is not available). I'm updating the question to point this out. Thanks for your reply anyway!